# Find whole word at beginning of string with preg_match?

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I am trying to find whole words e.g. 'Location:', 'Contact:', at the beginning of a string with preg_match.

Please could someone provide and quick example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

starts (`^`) with word character (`\w`) and has one or more of them (`+`) and should be captured and stored in $matches (brackets)

```
$in = "First word is captured";
preg_match("/^(\w+)/",$in,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```